# SQL SERVER Query Select by FirstName, Lastname

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `Products` table has almost 10,000 records where i want the "`artist`" ( varchar )  column name to sort by `Firstname and Lastname`. In the where clause i am sending initial letter of either first name or lastname. This Query works for few records but not for all, its probably because of the pattern of the records ?
Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE SUBSTRING(artist, 1, 1) Like 'C'
```

Doesnt return the records... the way i want it ...Few of the records of the table ( artist) column are below

```
Comtesse Mathilde duMonceau de Bergendael
Mulholland, S.J.
Cleminson
NULL
Samuel Jackson
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LIKE` clause is wrong. Also you should not be using `LIKE` at all here, as you're only filtering by one letter:

```
.... WHERE LEFT(artist, 1) = 'C'
```

**EDIT** `LEFT` is actually faster than `SUBSTRING`.

Also, you can not expect anything that's not starting with a `C` to be returned, as you're explicitly only asking for entries that start with a `C`.

I guess what you really need is the following:

```
.... WHERE LEFT(FirstName, 1) = 'C' OR LEFT(LastName, 1) = 'C' ORDER BY LastName, Firstname
```

If you only have the `Artist` column, things get complicated, as you actually *do* need to use `LIKE`, which makes things pretty slow

```
.... WHERE Artist LIKE `%C%`
```

returns any artist, the name of which contains a `C` anywhere in the name. This would also return these:

```
Clemens Test
Test Cutler
Arachnophobia
```

Comment: it's working in some cases only, Not in all , there are 5+ formt of data, query not working in all

Comment: The `LIKE` clause should work in any case. Show me one where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

User this where clause

```
where left(artist, 1) = 'C'
```

or

```
where artist like 'C%'
```